# React MomentJs not returning json time in minutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have a JSON file with delay time in seconds set in an object like this:

```
 "delay": 420,
```

When I map the object in React without moment, all 8 items in the json array return their times (ie 300, 420, 60 etc...) for each object.

```
const DelayTailLbl = (props) => {
  const [delayTailData, setDelayTailData] = useState(props.data);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>{delayTailData.delay}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default DelayTailLbl;
```

Now I am trying to convert seconds into minutes using set minutes from moment as shown in the docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/minute/

```
import moment from 'moment'

const DelayTailLbl = (props) => {
  const [delayTailData, setDelayTailData] = useState(props.data);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>{moment(delayTailData.delay).format("mm")}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default DelayTailLbl;
```

when I add moment, the time for all 8 objects return with 00 for minutes. If I change the time to `format("HH:mm:ss")`, it returns 00:00:00.

What is the proper way to return the JSON data as seconds using moment? I don't understand without it why it returns the correct data but with it, it returns nothing,

Comment: You missed this part in the link: *Accepts numbers from 0 to 59. If the range is exceeded, it will bubble up to the hour.*

Comment: `"delay": 420,` what is 420 here? mins, secs, millisecs?

Comment: 420 seconds @palaѕн

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I tried ```{moment(delayTailData.delay).minutes(59)}``` and other numbers but my web app doesn't load if I add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a date time object using `delayTailData.delay`

What you really want is to use the Moment Durations

[Moment Durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Using Moment Durations you can just `moment.duration(delayTailData.delay, 'seconds');` and if you want to friendly display that time you can do `moment.duration(delayTailData.delay, 'seconds').humanize();`

Comment: Thank you. The humanize function was able to correctly display the data. The first function didn't for some reason.

Comment: It's because the `moment.duration(delayTailData.delay, 'seconds')` creates an Object which you would have to call one of the "formatter" methods to show the time, like: `moment.duration(delayTailData.delay, 'seconds').asMinutes()`. 

You can call `asMilliseconds(); asSeconds(); asMinutes(); asDays(); asWeeks(), asMonths() and asYears()`.

Comment: I actually just came back here to tell you I found ```.asMinutes()``` in the docs.Thank again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like:

```js
const secs = 420;
const mins = moment.utc(secs*1000).format('mm');
const hhmmss = moment.utc(secs*1000).format('HH:mm:ss');

console.log('mm:\t', mins);
console.log('hhmmss:\t', hhmmss);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```